# Using my own button icons instead of default icons

Tags: android-layout

My application has a ADD button and a DELETE button. I'm using the default icons

(1) android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
(2) android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"

These buttons pop up when I press the Menu button on the emulator.
However I would like to use my own buttons instead of the default icons in the relative layout.
Is it possible to use to a png file of my choice(both for button selected and button not selected) as a add button and delete button?
Could any of you please share some information on this?

Regards
Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use your own buttons: just replace the icon attribute in the menu xml file. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html for the details to set your own icon: you can copy your own PNGs into the `res/drawable` folder and then point to it in the menu xml file.